# Why does my firewall (iptables) interfere in my bridge (brctl)?

Tags: iptables, virtual-machine, firewall, bridge

I set up a bridge `br0` "attached" to two interfaces:

- `eth0`, my physical interface connected to the real LAN,
- `vnet0`, a KVM virtual interface (connected to a Windows VM).

And I have this single firewall rule in the forward chain:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

*Now, the only ping that is working is from the VM to the host.*

The `br0` interface owns the IP address of my host machine. `eth0` and `vnet0` do not "own" any IP, from the host point of view. The Windows VM has a static IP configuration.

If change my `iptables` rule to `ACCEPT` (or even use a more restrictive `iptables -A FORWARD -o br0 -j ACCEPT`), everything is working fine! (i.e. I can ping any LAN machine from the VM, and the other way round too).

All IP forwarding kernel options are disabled (like `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0`).

**So, how can the netfilter firewall block something that is not even enabled?**

Furthermore, the VM - LAN traffic  should only imply `eth0` and `vnet0`. Yet it looks like allowing FORWARD traffic with `-o br0` "works" (I did not check very carefully though).

Comment: Take a look at my A to this U&L Q: [Settings when using a bridge](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125599/settings-when-using-a-bridge/125603#125603)

Comment: What's the output of `sysctl -a | grep bridge-nf`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas 
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged = 0`
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged = 0`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136918/why-does-my-firewall-iptables-interfere-in-my-bridge-brctl/148082#comment-218527) from Stéphane Chazelas provides the hint to the answer.

According to [Bridge-nf Frequently Asked Questions](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/misc/brnf-faq.html) bridge-nf enables iptables, ip6tables or arptables to see bridged traffic.

As of kernel version 2.6.1, there are five [sysctl entries](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=v3.16#n1438) for bridge-nf behavioral control:

- `bridge-nf-call-arptables` - pass bridged ARP traffic to arptables' FORWARD chain.
- `bridge-nf-call-iptables` - pass bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables' chains.
- `bridge-nf-call-ip6tables` - pass bridged IPv6 traffic to ip6tables' chains.
- `bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged` - pass bridged vlan-tagged ARP/IP traffic to arptables/iptables.
- `net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged` - pass bridged pppoe-tagged IP/IPv6 traffic to {ip,ip6}tables

You can disable netfilter firewall blocking with:

```
# sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
# sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
```

Comment: Since Linux 3.18, the functionality where iptables handles packets from the bridge can be disabled by not loading the `br_netfilter` module. Not having the module loaded also means that there is no `/proc/sys/net/bridge/` entry.

Comment: And [since Linux kernel 5.3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=22567590b2e634247931b3d2351384ba45720ebe) this feature becomes per namespace instead of global.