# Fedora-25 HOST + CentOS-6 GUESTS Linux/LXC: Guests can't connect to each other or to default router

Tags: centos, networking, fedora, lxc, container

I also submitted this as a Fedora bug question, [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1477365).

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but here is my sudden issue.

**The Linux/LXC single-box cluster setup**

- I use Fedora x86_64 (currently Fedora-25) as the LXC/HOST O/S. I use
  CentOS-6 x86_64 (currently CentOS-6.9 Final) for the six (qty. 6)
  LXC/GUEST O/S'.
- This was working for a long time (a few years), but suddenly does not
  after a 'sudo dnf -y update' (HOST) and 'sudo yum -y update'
  (GUESTS). It has been a few months since I booted this HOST/GUESTS
  LXC "cluster" and, as usual, O/S updates are the first thing that I
  perform. This may provide a hint if some underlying system-level
  component(s)/behavior(s) changed during that time.
- The Fedora HOST and CentOS-6 GUESTS are on the same subnet, and share
  the same default router: 192.168.0.0/24; 192.168.0.1 (all standard
  stuff).
- The Fedora Host does not have any firewall/firewalld RPM packages
  installed, and therefore doesn't not run a firewall. I removed this
  long ago to simplify things.

**The issue**

- After performing the above O/S updates to the HOST and GUESTS, from within any GUEST, I can no longer **(a)** successfully ping/ssh guest-to-guest or **(b)** ping the default router.
- I can, however, ping/ssh HOST-to-GUEST and GUEST-to-HOST with no issue.
- From any computer outside this setup -- which, by the way, are also on the same subnet and share the same default router as above -- I can ping/ssh to the HOST but cannot to any of the GUESTS.
- Other than performing the aforementioned O/S updates, I didn't alter
  anything.

**Some output**

- Here is output from the HOST: [HOST.txt](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1307821)
- Here is output from a GUEST: [ONE_GUEST.txt](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1307822)
- Note that the GUESTS are named vps00, vps01, vps02, vps03, vps04 and
  vps10, and have identical configurations except MAC and IP addresses
  (so I only provided output for one of them). While the HOST is named
  lxc-host. Throughout the attachments, you'll see some in-line notes
  that I annotated them with.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the **accepted** answer in this [POST](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125599/settings-when-using-a-bridge), I was able to finally figure out the **iptables(1M)** entries that were missing. Here they are:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

I don't know what Fedora HOST O/S changes occurred to make these entries not be there suddenly (meaning after doing  "**dnf -y update; reboot**" after a few months of not doing that), but would sure love to know because now I have to hardcode these entries in somewhere (which I'm not thrilled about LoL).

I hope this helps others who bridge their LXC guests like I do.

**ADDITION-1:**

Here are the sequence of commands I used to permanently incorporate them,
after interactively executive the above commands (in-memory):

```
root# cd /etc/sysconfig/
root# cp iptables iptables.FCS               # Backup the current contents.
root# iptables-save > ./iptables             # Overwrite with in-memory contents.
root# reboot
root# sudo systemctl start iptables.service  # Not yet committed.
root# sudo iptables -L -n -v | more          # Inspect in-memory. changes
root# sudo systemctl enable iptables.service # If all looks good, commit them permanently.
```